# New equivalent for old onPlatform method used in C# WITH Type Arguement

Tags: c#, xamarin

So I'm in this udemy class, and they used a deprecated piece of code below. I realize a switch or if statement would work for this, but I wanted to see if there was something other than RuntimePlatform with a switch to replace this. I did like this functionality after all.

```
Device.OnPlatform<Thickness>(
iOS: new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
Android: new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0),
WinPhone: new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0));
```

Admittedly it did not appear like it, but i'm hoping to be pleasantly surprised!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to not surprise you... As you know this has been depreciated, the idea is to use `Device.RuntimePlatform` which returns a `string`.

No, there is no other method unless you make one. If you really dislike the `switch` syntax, you could use a *switch expression* though

```
var something = Device.RuntimePlatform switch
{
   "iOS" => new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
   "Android" => new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0),
   "WinPhone" =>  new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0),
   _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
};
```